# Can someone explain how to post an image and text on tumblr using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, tumblr

I'm new to programing in ruby or any web languages so I don't really know how to use tumblr's API or any other websites.

I would assume that you could request JSON from another site and post it there using your login info but I have no Idea how to do this. I just need an example I can learn from.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client

^^ is a great place for you to start. But the basic gist of getting started is by setting up a controller and some views to communicate with the tumblr API. Go to your terminal and run these commands:

```
rails g controller tumblr
rails g model tumblr index
```

Now that you have those setup, go to your Gemfile, located in the root directory of your project and add this line to your Gemfile, somewhere in the middle.

```
gem 'tumblr_client'
```

Then go back to your terminal window and execute:

```
bundle install
```

OR

```
bundle update
```

Now that you have your Gem installed, we can begin setting up your connection. A good reference for this is the tumblr Gem's repo: https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client

Somewhere in your new controller, located in app/controllers/tumblr, create a new method. Let's name it tumblr_connect

```
def tumblr_connect(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
  Tumblr.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = consumer_key
  config.consumer_secret = consumer_secret
  config.oauth_token = access_token
  config.oauth_token_secret = access_token_secret
end
```

To call your method simply execute:

```
tumblr_connect(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
```

Replace consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, and access_token_secret with the proper settings that are provided through tumblr. You can set that up here: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

OK! You can now communicate with tumblr through your application!! It is good practice to test your code out using the rails console. You can start it by navigating to the root directory of your folder in the terminal and running the command:

```
rails console
```

OR SIMPLY:

```
rails c
```

copy the tumblr_connect method from def to end and paste it in to the console. You can call it directly from there.

Once your connection is setup you can create a client and get/send requests to the tumblr server:

```
client = Tumblr::Client.new
client.info
```

Read the tumblr documentation for more information.